# how to update a value exist in array in quasar

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

i declared array as

`const myproducts = ref([] )`

After that i pushed value to array. Now `myproducts` is like

```
[ { "id": 1, "qty": 1 }, { "id": 7, "qty": 1 } ]

 var old_qty = myproducts.value.find(x => x.id === id).qty
 var new_qty = old_qty +1
```

How can i increment  qty exist in array with id 1 with new_qty ?

TIA

Comment: computed properties is what you need : https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html

Answer (score 0):

```
   var old_qty = myproducts.value.find(x => x.id === id).qty
   var new_qty = old_qty +1
   myproducts.value.find(x => x.id === id).qty = new_qty
```

or

```
myproducts.value.find(x => x.id === id).qty+=1;
```